# How to coolaborate work in LAN network with google earth?

Tags: lan, google-earth, kml

We have two computers connected in LAN network and we would like to work in the same task with google earth, so we want every changing saved synchronically, such as paths or shapefiles etc...
How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to do the work on one computer and share the screen
using [TeamViewer](https://www.teamviewer.com/).

For TeamViewer to be used within a local network (LAN), you will need to
go into the TeamViewer **Options**--> **General** --> **Incoming LAN Connections** --> change to **Accept** (see [link](https://community.teamviewer.com/t5/Knowledge-Base/Can-TeamViewer-be-used-within-a-local-network-LAN-only/ta-p/4618)).

[image]